# ArrayProxy behaving like a singleton

Tags: ember.js

If I have a custom ArrayProxy like this:

```
App.MyArrayProxy = Ember.ArrayProxy.extend()
```

And I create an instance of it in the init of a controller from a  control {{control 'foo/bar'}}

Like this:

```
  init: ->
    @_super.apply this, arguments
    @set 'property', App.MyArrayProxy.create()
```

It appears that this ArrayProxy is a singleton, i.e. all instances of the control share the same instance of the arrayproxy.  Is this the case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should not be a singleton. Are you setting and initial content value? E.g.

`App.MyArrayProxy = Ember.ArrayProxy.extend({content: []});`

In the case above the content would be shared giving the potential illusion of a singleton.

Comment: that was indeed the problem.  Creating the content in init solved the problem.